# How can I make my javascript only make the max numbers 4 and only numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do my school coursework and I need to make my javascipt examination number only allow numbers and maximum 4 numbers, I have searched google and tried possible stuff, but I can't seem to find the answer. Anyone know? thanks

Comment: Could you please share with us this "possible stuff" that you have tried?

Comment: I'm sure your course teachers would not approve simply asking the users of [so] to do your assignment for you.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The teachers are allowing us to use stackoverflow, they have unblocked the site so we can simply ask but we need to reference the question to our coursework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is simply use an if statement between 0 and 9999 ie

```
var examNumber = 32353;

if(examNumber<=9999 && examNumber>=0){
//Correct Number
}else{
//Incorrect Number
}
```

**JSFiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/affp3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 45) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and this your your second question element.txtName.value.length;try this